# Display featured post of image being hovered in wp

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, post

I'm trying to make a simplistic website that only shows the post image after you hover on a title. The problem is I can't get my JS to work.
With some previous tips I got here on how to go about doing this I first list all the post images with their URL as an ID (makes it easier to compare) in a PHP shortcode snippet:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        //Useless
        // echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        // echo '<li>' . get_permalink() . '</li>';
    
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<figure class="popUp" id="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</figure>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

In CSS I set the display properties of PopUp to none.
Up to this point everything is as expected. But now the JS comes in. I want to get the URL of a hovered post and if it is the same as the URL(in CSS the ID) of the post I want it to display. When hovering stops I also want the image to disapear.

```
document.getElementById("carousel").addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var hoveredEl = event.target; // The actual element which was hovered.
    if (hoveredEl.tagName !== 'A') { return; } // Ignore non links
    const addCSS = s =>(d=>{d.head.appendChild(d.createElement("style")).innerHTML=s})(document);
    // Usage: 
    addCSS("#" + hoveredEl + " { display: inline-block; }";)
});

document.getElementById("carousel").addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    var hoveredEl = event.target; // The actual element which was hovered.
    if (hoveredEl.tagName !== 'A') { return; } // Ignore non links
    const addCSS = s =>(d=>{d.head.appendChild(d.createElement("style")).innerHTML=s})(document);
    // Usage: 
    addCSS("#" + hoveredEl + " { display: none; }";)
});
```

I put it on the page as a shortcode JS snippet in the same DIV as the PHP code but in a different to the links being hovered (could that be the iss). Is there any obvious red flags in the JS code?

Edit: Closed figure tag and used the event listener on a specific DIV. Still no luck...

Comment: I'm still looking over your code but just want to point out you are not closing your `<figure>` tag with a `</figure>` anywhere so that could be an issue.

Comment: Should you be closing that `<figure>` tag at some point? Also, putting the url as the `id` is bad practice... your JS also looks like it's being attached to EVERY `mouseover` and `mouseout` event, which is going to slow down your browser. Best to attach the event to the actual object you'd like to target.

Comment: Is this a good summary of what you'd like to do? On the posts Index page, you'd like to show the thumbnail of each post upon hovering on the post title. Is that correct?

Comment: @qotsa42 Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I closed off the figure tag now. I will try to attach it to that div thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (note the new `hover-target` class):

```php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
    
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a class='hover-target' href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<figure class="popUp" id="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</figure>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

```js
jQuery('.hover-target').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('figure').show()
}, function(e){
    $(this).siblings('figure').hide()
})
```

This assumes the thumbnails are hidden by default, with a rule such as this:

```css
.popUp {
    display: none;
}
```

This works because you are using jQuery's [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to pass two separate functions, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`. On `mouseenter`, display the image. On `mouseleave`, hide the image.